# Continuous Integration and deployment of multiple projects in single git repository

Tags: continuous-integration, microservices

I'm wondering if there is some good way to make CI/CD for single git repository that contains many projects. I often work with microservices, but I always preferred to have separate repo for each project and thanks to that I had separate pipelines for each repo. Now I'm in situation where all microservices are in single repo and I would like to know if there is some good way to make it work. The question is general because I don't have any CI tool right now, probably going to use Gitlab CI or Jenkins if I'm gonna need something more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you need to understand that your pipeline can be too big depending how many microservices you have in this repo

look here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

you are able to add a lot of only/except conditions to avoid or force some specific steps

example

build only if folder x is changed
test only if microservice x was built.... except if branch is example